# VBA Transparent ActiveX object becomes opaque on click

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I'm currently attempting to create a mouse "Roll Over" script in Excel, where when the user mouses over a button it runs a macro.

To establish this, I created 1 Shape and 2 ActiveX Labels. The way they are layered is:

- Top Layer: Label1 (Reads Mouseover to activate) and is just slightly
  wider than the visible button
- Middle Layer: Shape1 which is where the perceived button is
- Bottom Layer: Label2 which is the largest, and "clears" the macro
  when the user moves out of the hitbox of Label 1.

Visually it looks like this if I don't use transparency.

[image]

The issue I'm having, is once I set the two labels to be transparent, if the user happens to click in their hitbox areas it will cause the label to appear and become fully opaque in the original color chosen.

I can somewhat mitigate this with:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Label2.Visible = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

But this causes the Label to "Flash" opaque and then quickly disappear. I've tried setting the label to become transparent on click but it doesn't work. I cannot seem to get around this and it may just be a limitation to using activeX.  Unfortunately, I need the activeX to use the mousemove event.

Hoping someone out there has a clever workaround or solution! Thanks in advance!

edit: In case it wasn't clear, here's a simplistic example of what I'd do. Where you rollover the button, it displays a value somewhere and when you're out of the hitbox it will clear the value.  The issue is only when a user clicks on the transparent label, it will flash opaque.

```
Private Sub Label2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    'Clear Value in Cell(1,1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).ClearContents
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
   'Display Value in Cell(1,1)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Hello World"
End Sub
```

Comment: What happens if you change the back/fore-colours to none?

Comment: I'd post a very, very similar answer here as I did on the linked duplicate: don't use an ActiveX control. Make a rounded-rectangle shape, style as needed, assign to a macro - you'll get consistent transparency, and a nice hand-cursor on hover, for free.

Comment: Hi Mathieu, not fully understanding. If I use shapes, then how can I use mousemove events to trigger macros when the user rollsover the transparent button? It was my understanding shapes cannot use mousemove events? Am I wrong?

Comment: SJR: Not familiar with how to set back/fore colors to none? I thought they require a hex code? How do I set to none?

Comment: Something like this as a workaround? Label1.BackColor = Range(Label1.TopLeftCell.Address).Interior.Color